# PHP Generator object not receiving data from processed external JSON API

Tags: php, json, curl, joomla

I have been converting a Joomla 3-based CLI script to a Joomla 4/5-based API script using this [resource](https://github.com/alexandreelise/j4x-api-examples/blob/master/using-raw-php/turn-your-top-5-favorite-movies-into-joomla-articles-omdb-api.php) as reference. The script retrieves news posts from an external API and adds them to Joomla as individual articles.

I have the `$process` function working. It successfully connects with the external API and outputs the data array in the browser when using the `print_r` function. I have included the full `$process` function below.

```
$process = function (string $givenHttpVerb, string $endPoint, string $dataString, array $headers, int $timeOut, $transport) {
  curl_setopt_array($transport, [
      CURLOPT_URL            => $endPoint,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'utf-8',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => $timeOut,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_SSLVERSION     => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => $givenHttpVerb,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $dataString,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
    ]
  );

  $response = curl_exec($transport);

  if (empty($response)) {
    throw new RuntimeException( 'Empty output', 422 );
  }
  return $response;
};
```

The `$process` function is called using `$dataSourceResponse = $process($dataSourceHttpVerb, $dataSourceUrl, $dataSourceDataString, $dataSourceHeaders, $dataSourceTimeout, $dataSourceTransport);`

I have a `$generator` function that accepts the `$dataSourceResponse` anonymous function and the `$apiUrl`, which is for the Joomla-based site. The `$apiUrl` is *upgrade.domain.com/api/index.php/v1*. The full `$generator` function is included below.

```
$generator = function (string $dataSourceResponse): Generator {
  if (empty($dataSourceResponse)) {
    yield new RuntimeException( 'DTN API response must not be empty', 422 );
  }

  $resource = json_decode($dataSourceResponse);

  if ($resource === false) {
    yield new RuntimeException( 'Could not read response from source DTN API', 500 );
  }

  try {
    foreach ($resource as $article) {
      $data = [
        'id' => 0,
        'catid' => 13,
        'title' => $article->title,
        'articletext' => $article->content,
        'introtext' => $article->storySummary,
        'fulltext' => $article->content,
        'note' => $article->topic,
        'state' => 1,
        'access' => 1,
        'created_by' => 386,
        'created_by_alias' => 'DTN News',
        'language' => '*',
      ];
    }
    $dataString = json_encode($data);
  } finally {
    echo 'Done processing data' . PHP_EOL;
  }
};
```

The `$generator` function is called using `$postData = $generator($dataSourceResponse, $apiUrl);`

When I use `print_r` for the `$postData` variable, the following is displayed in the browser: `Generator Object() Done processing data`.

It seems to me that the data retrieved from the external API is not being successfully shared with the `$generator` function for inserting the news post items into Joomla articles via the API.

I have included the full PHP script below for reference.

```
declare(strict_types=1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);

$dataSourceUrl = 'https://api.dtn.com/publishing/news/articles?categoryId=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C16%2C17&limit=10&maxAge=15&apikey=redacted';
$apiUrl = 'https://upgrade.domain.com/api/index.php/v1';
$token = redacted;
$timeOut = 60;

$generator = function (string $dataSourceResponse): Generator {
  if (empty($dataSourceResponse)) {
    yield new RuntimeException( 'DTN API response must not be empty', 422 );
  }

  $resource = json_decode($dataSourceResponse);

  if ($resource === false) {
    yield new RuntimeException( 'Could not read response from source DTN API', 500 );
  }

  try {
    foreach ($resource as $article) {
      $data = [
        'id' => 0,
        'catid' => 13,
        'title' => $article->title,
        'articletext' => $article->content,
        'introtext' => $article->storySummary,
        'fulltext' => $article->content,
        'note' => $article->topic,
        'state' => 1,
        'access' => 1,
        'created_by' => 386,
        'created_by_alias' => 'DTN News',
        'language' => '*',
      ];
    }
    $dataString = json_encode($data);
  } finally {
    echo 'Done processing data' . PHP_EOL;
  }
};

$process = function (string $givenHttpVerb, string $endPoint, string $dataString, array $headers, int $timeOut, $transport) {
  curl_setopt_array($transport, [
      CURLOPT_URL            => $endPoint,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'utf-8',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => $timeOut,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_SSLVERSION     => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => $givenHttpVerb,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $dataString,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
    ]
  );

  $response = curl_exec($transport);

  if (empty($response)) {
    throw new RuntimeException( 'Empty output', 422 );
  }
  return $response;
};

$dataSourceHttpVerb = 'GET';
$dataSourceDataString = '';
$dataSourceHeaders = [
  'Accept: application/json',
  'Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br',
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Connection: keep-alive',
];
$dataSourceTimeout = 60;
$dataSourceTransport = curl_init();

try {
  $dataSourceResponse = $process($dataSourceHttpVerb, $dataSourceUrl,   $dataSourceDataString, $dataSourceHeaders, $dataSourceTimeout, $dataSourceTransport);
  $postData = $generator($dataSourceResponse, $apiUrl);

  foreach ($postData as $dataString) {
    if (!is_string($dataString)) {
      continue;
    }
    $curl = curl_init();
    try {
      $headers = [
        'Accept: application/vnd.api+json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-length: ' . mb_strlen($dataString),
        sprintf('X-Joomla-Token: %s', trim($token)),
      ];
  
      $output = $process('POST', $apiUrl, $dataString, $headers, $timeOut, $curl);
  
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
      continue;
    } finally {
      curl_close($curl);
    }
  }
} catch (Throwable $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
} finally {
  curl_close($dataSourceTransport);
}
```

Here is functioning PHP `foreach loop` from the CLI-based script that I have tried adapting for reference.

```
foreach ($articles as $article) {
  $articleData = [
    'id' => 0,
    'catid' => 13,
    'title' => $article->title,
    'introtext' => $article->storySummary,
    'fulltext' => $article->content,
    'note' => $article->topic,
    'state' => 1,
    'access' => 1,
    'created_by' => 386,
    'created_by_alias' => 'DTN News',
    'language' => '*',
  ];

  if (!$articleModel->save($articleData)) {
    throw new Exception($articleModel->getError());
  }
}
```

**Update**

Output from using `var_dump(json_encode($data)); die();` on the data array:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "catid": 13,
  "title": "DTN Midday Livestock Comments",
  "articletext": "Firm gains redeveloped early Wednesday morning in live cattle and feeder cattle trade. This support has helped to spark some underlying follow-through buying in nearby and deferred contracts, supporting triple-digit gains through the morning. Hog futures are lightly traded but holding narrow losses at midday based on softness in pork fundamentals.<\\/span>",
  "introtext": "Firm gains redeveloped early Wednesday morning in live cattle and feeder cattle trade. This support has helped to spark some underlying follow-through buying in nearby and deferred contracts, supporting triple-digit gains through the morning. Hog futures are lightly traded but holding narrow losses at midday based on softness in pork fundamentals.<\\/span>",
  "fulltext": "Firm gains redeveloped early Wednesday morning in live cattle and feeder cattle trade. This support has helped to spark some underlying follow-through buying in nearby and deferred contracts, supporting triple-digit gains through the morning. Hog futures are lightly traded but holding narrow losses at midday based on softness in pork fundamentals.<\\/span>",
  "note": "DTN\\/Ag\\/Markets",
  "state": 1,
  "access": 1,
  "created_by": 386,
  "created_by_alias": "DTN News",
  "language": "*"
}
```

Comment: You're not actually yielding anything from your generator function when it succeeds...

Comment: @Nick I have changed `$dataString = json_encode($data);` to `yield json_encode($data);`, but there is still no output from the generator function. The resource example I shared defines the yield the same way, except for combining arrays.

Comment: hmmm... have you checked that `$process` is actually returning any articles?

Comment: @Nick Yes, `var_dump($dataSourceResponse);` on the PHP script displays the expected data from the external JSON API. You can see it in [action here](https://upgrade.plosz.ca/api-post.php)

Comment: @Nick When I `var_dump(json_encode($data)); die();` the `$data` array from the foreach, a single result is displayed in the browser. There should be up to three displayed for today's news feed. I have added this output to my original question.

Comment: That points out a new problem; `$data = [ 'id' => 0, ...` should be `$data[] = [  'id' => 0,` as you're overwriting `$data` in each pass of the `foreach ($resource as $article)` loop. Or possibly, the `yield json_encode($data)` should be moved inside the foreach loop. Without knowing what format the joomla update expects I can't be sure.

Comment: @Nick I have tried changing `$data` to `$data[]` and having the yield inside and outside of the foreach, but am having no success. Joomla 4 provides a RESTful web services API for intaking content for articles, fields, etc. When I `var_dump($postData)` the browser displays `object(Generator)#4 (0) { } `.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not at all familiar with Joomla, let alone its API. I've pointed out the issues I can see in the code; maybe you should consider posting on [joomla.se] as you might find more experts there. Or perhaps @mickmackusa can help, he is an expert.

Comment: @Nick I was able to solve my issues by referring back to the resource and refactoring my code. Your suggestions also helped resolve the issues. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working, and that I managed to help even if only a little judging by your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issues by refactoring my code and implementing some missing functionality from the [resource](https://github.com/alexandreelise/j4x-api-examples/blob/master/using-raw-php/turn-your-top-5-favorite-movies-into-joomla-articles-omdb-api.php) I was using as the basis for this script. I have highlighted the refactored code and newly implemented code below as well as the full script for reference.

The `$data foreach loop` was refactored by moving the `yield (json_encode($data));` inside of the loop. I have also added string manipulation functions to clean up some of the imported text content.

```
// Strip CSS classes from tags without removing the tags themselves
$stripClasses = '/\bclass=["\'][^"\']*["\']/';

foreach ($resource as $article) {
  $data = [
    'id' => 0,
    'catid' => 13,
    'title' => ucwords(strtolower($article->title)),
    'alias' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', urlencode($article->title))),
    'articletext' => $article->content,
    'introtext' => $article->storySummary,
    'fulltext' => $article->content,
    'note' => 'DTN supplied topics: ' . str_replace('/', ', ', $article->topic),
    'state' => 1,
    'access' => 1,
    'created_by' => 386,
    'created_by_alias' => 'DTN News',
    'language' => '*',
  ];
  
  if (isset($data['articletext']) && !empty($data['articletext'])) {
    $data['articletext'] = strip_tags($data['articletext'], $allowedTags);
    $data['articletext'] = preg_replace($stripClasses, '', $data['articletext']);
  } else {
    $data['articletext'] = '';
  }
  if (isset($data['introtext']) && !empty($data['introtext'])) {
    $data['introtext'] = strip_tags($data['introtext'], $allowedTags);
    $data['introtext'] = preg_replace($stripClasses, '', $data['introtext']);
  } else {
    $data['introtext'] = '';
  }
  if (isset($data['fulltext']) && !empty($data['fullotext'])) {
    $data['fulltext'] = strip_tags($data['fulltext'], $allowedTags);
    $data['fulltext'] = preg_replace($stripClasses, '', $data['fulltext']);
  } else {
    $data['fulltext'] = '';
  }
  
  if ($data === false) {
  } else {
    yield (json_encode(
      $data
    ));
  }
}
```

I included this anonymous function from the resource to handle the external and Joomla endpoints. This was essential to resolving the `404 Resource not found` error I was encountering as I worked on refactoring the code.

```
$endPoint = function (string $givenBaseUrl, string $givenBasePath, int $givenResourceId = 0): string {
  return $givenResourceId ? sprintf('%s/%s/%s/%d', $givenBaseUrl, $givenBasePath, 'content/articles', $givenResourceId)
: sprintf('%s/%s/%s', $givenBaseUrl, $givenBasePath, 'content/articles');
};
```

I removed the `$apiUrl` variable from the `$postData` anonymous function as it was not necessary.

```
$postData = $generator($dataSourceResponse);
```

The first `foreach loop` in the final `try > catch > finally` wads refactored to check for `PATCH` or `POST` of the API and to handle the newly included `$endPoint` anonymous function.

```
$storage = [];
foreach ($postData as $dataString) {
  if (!is_string($dataString)) {
    continue;
  }
  $curl = curl_init();
  try {
    $decodedDataString = json_decode($dataString);
    if ($decodedDataString === false) {
      continue;
    }
  
    $headers = [
      'Accept: application/vnd.api+json',
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Content-length: ' . mb_strlen($dataString),
      sprintf('X-Joomla-Token: %s', trim($token)),
    ];
    $pk = (int) $decodedDataString->id;
    $output = $process($pk ? 'PATCH' : 'POST', $endPoint($baseUrl, $basePath, 0), $dataString, $headers, $timeOut, $curl);
  
    $decodedJsonOutput = json_decode($output);
  
    if (isset($decodedJsonOutput->errors)) {
      $storage[] = ['mightExists' => $decodedJsonOutput->errors[0]->code === 400, 'decodedDataString' => $decodedDataString];
      continue;
    }
  
  } catch (Throwable $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    continue;
  } finally {
    curl_close($curl);
  }
}
```

The second `foreach loop` was added to handle errors and check for duplicate aliases of the Joomla articles.

```
foreach ($storage as $item) {
  $storageCurl = curl_init();
  try {
    if ($item['mightExists']) {
      $pk = (int) $item['decodedDataString']->id;
      $item['decodedDataString']->alias = sprintf('%s-%s', $item['decodedDataString']->alias, bin2hex(random_bytes(4)));
      // No need to do another json_encode anymore
      $dataString = json_encode($item['decodedDataString']);
      // HTTP request headers
      $headers = [
        'Accept: application/vnd.api+json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . mb_strlen($dataString),
        sprintf('X-Joomla-Token: %s', trim($token)),
      ];
      $output = $process($pk ? 'PATCH' : 'POST', $endPoint($baseUrl, $basePath, 0), $dataString, $headers, $timeOut, $storageCurl);
    }
  } catch (Throwable $storageThrowable) {
    echo $storageThrowable->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    continue;
  } finally {
    curl_close($storageCurl);
  }
}
```

**Full script**

```
declare(strict_types=1);
// ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);

$dataSourceUrl = Redacted;

$baseUrl= Redacted;
$basePath = 'api/index.php/v1';
$token = Redacted;

$timeOut = 120;

$generator = function (string $dataSourceResponse): Generator {
  if (empty($dataSourceResponse)) {
    yield new RuntimeException( 'DTN API response must not be empty', 422 );
  }

  $resource = json_decode($dataSourceResponse);

  if ($resource === false) {
    yield new RuntimeException( 'Could not read response from source DTN API', 500 );
  }

  $allowedTags = ['p', 'img', 'table'];
  $stripClasses = '/\bclass=["\'][^"\']*["\']/';

  try {
    foreach ($resource as $article) {
      $data = [
        'id' => 0,
        'catid' => 13,
        'title' => ucwords(strtolower($article->title)),
        'alias' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', urlencode($article->title))),
        'articletext' => $article->content,
        'introtext' => $article->storySummary,
        'fulltext' => $article->content,
        'note' => 'DTN supplied topics: ' . str_replace('/', ', ', $article->topic),
        'state' => 1,
        'access' => 1,
        'created_by' => 386,
        'created_by_alias' => 'DTN News',
        'language' => '*',
      ];
  
      if (isset($data['articletext']) && !empty($data['articletext'])) {
        $data['articletext'] = strip_tags($data['articletext'], $allowedTags);
        $data['articletext'] = preg_replace($stripClasses, '', $data['articletext']);
      } else {
        $data['articletext'] = '';
      }
      if (isset($data['introtext']) && !empty($data['introtext'])) {
        $data['introtext'] = strip_tags($data['introtext'], $allowedTags);
        $data['introtext'] = preg_replace($stripClasses, '', $data['introtext']);
      } else {
        $data['introtext'] = '';
      }
      if (isset($data['fulltext']) && !empty($data['fullotext'])) {
        $data['fulltext'] = strip_tags($data['fulltext'], $allowedTags);
        $data['fulltext'] = preg_replace($stripClasses, '', $data['fulltext']);
      } else {
        $data['fulltext'] = '';
      }
  
      if ($data === false) {
      } else {
        yield (json_encode(
          $data
        ));
      }
    }
  } finally {
    // echo 'Done processing data' . PHP_EOL;
  }
};

$endPoint = function (string $givenBaseUrl, string $givenBasePath, int $givenResourceId = 0): string {
  return $givenResourceId ? sprintf('%s/%s/%s/%d', $givenBaseUrl, $givenBasePath, 'content/articles', $givenResourceId)
: sprintf('%s/%s/%s', $givenBaseUrl, $givenBasePath, 'content/articles');
};

$process = function (string $givenHttpVerb, string $endPoint, string   $dataString, array $headers, int $timeOut, $transport) {
  curl_setopt_array($transport, [
      CURLOPT_URL            => $endPoint,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'utf-8',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => $timeOut,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_SSLVERSION     => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => $givenHttpVerb,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $dataString,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
    ]
  );

  $response = curl_exec($transport);

  if (empty($response)) {
    throw new RuntimeException( 'Empty output', 422 );
  }
  return $response;
};

$dataSourceHttpVerb = 'GET';
$dataSourceDataString = '';
$dataSourceHeaders = [
  'Accept: application/json',
  'Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br',
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Connection: keep-alive',
];
$dataSourceTimeout = 120;
$dataSourceTransport = curl_init();

try {
  $dataSourceResponse = $process($dataSourceHttpVerb, $dataSourceUrl, $dataSourceDataString, $dataSourceHeaders, $dataSourceTimeout, $dataSourceTransport);
  $postData = $generator($dataSourceResponse);

  $storage = [];
  foreach ($postData as $dataString) {
    if (!is_string($dataString)) {
      continue;
    }
    $curl = curl_init();
    try {
      $decodedDataString = json_decode($dataString);
      if ($decodedDataString === false) {
        continue;
      }
  
      $headers = [
        'Accept: application/vnd.api+json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-length: ' . mb_strlen($dataString),
        sprintf('X-Joomla-Token: %s', trim($token)),
      ];
      $pk = (int) $decodedDataString->id;
      $output = $process($pk ? 'PATCH' : 'POST', $endPoint($baseUrl, $basePath, 0), $dataString, $headers, $timeOut, $curl);
  
      $decodedJsonOutput = json_decode($output);
  
      if (isset($decodedJsonOutput->errors)) {
        $storage[] = ['mightExists' => $decodedJsonOutput->errors[0]->code === 400, 'decodedDataString' => $decodedDataString];
        continue;
      }
  
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
      continue;
    } finally {
      curl_close($curl);
    }
  }

  foreach ($storage as $item) {
    $storageCurl = curl_init();
    try {
      if ($item['mightExists']) {
        $pk = (int) $item['decodedDataString']->id;
        $item['decodedDataString']->alias = sprintf('%s-%s', $item['decodedDataString']->alias, bin2hex(random_bytes(4)));
        // No need to do another json_encode anymore
        $dataString = json_encode($item['decodedDataString']);
        // HTTP request headers
        $headers = [
          'Accept: application/vnd.api+json',
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          'Content-Length: ' . mb_strlen($dataString),
          sprintf('X-Joomla-Token: %s', trim($token)),
        ];
        $output = $process($pk ? 'PATCH' : 'POST', $endPoint($baseUrl, $basePath, 0), $dataString, $headers, $timeOut, $storageCurl);
      }
    } catch (Throwable $storageThrowable) {
      echo $storageThrowable->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
      continue;
    } finally {
      curl_close($storageCurl);
    }
  }
} catch (Throwable $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
} finally {
  curl_close($dataSourceTransport);
}
```